# inheritance & objective-c

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

this is my h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Base : NSObject

@end
```

this is my m file:

```
#import "Base.h"
@interface Base()
@property (nonatomic) int number;
@end

@implementation Base

-(void) setNumber: (int) p_number
{
    self.number = p_number;
}

@end
```

this is what i want to accomplish
an h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Base.h"

@interface Derived : Base

@end
```

and to do this in the m file

```
#import "Derived.h"

@implementation Derived

- (void) foo
{
    self.number= 7;
}

@end
```

this of course results in error, please answer with a code that allows me to call the base property **without placing the definition in the h file**

thanks

Comment: You have to working answers - you should accept one so this is marked as answered

Comment: @Paul.s can i accept both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same approach that Apple uses with `UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h`

e.g. Create

```
// BaseSubclass.h

@interface Base (ForSubclassEyesOnly)

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger number;

@end
```

You'll need to silence the compiler with

```
@implementation Base (ForSubclassEyesOnly)

@dynamic number;

@end
```

Now any class that want's to use these properties/call methods just includes this header.

e.g

```
#import "Derived.h"
#import "BaseSubclass.h"

@implementation Derived

- (void) foo
{
  self.number = 7;
}

@end
```

Comment: what if i wanted to override the setNumber method, i can't use the self.number cause it will cause recursion, and i can't use the _number member cause it's not recognized

Answer (score 4):

Asking people to answer only with code is not a good idea. Why not ask for an explanation of what's wrong, so that you can fix this error *and* tons of similar errors in the future yourself?

The problem here is that you don't declare your property in the base header. If you don't want to do that, you can declare it in your subclass' implementation file as an extension of your base class:

**Derived.m**

```
#import "Derived.h"

@interface Base () 
@property (nonatomic) int number;
@end

@implementation Derived

- (void) foo
{
    self.number= 7;
}

@end
```

Comment: This seems like a fairly sneaky way of achieving the desired effect. The `Base` extension should probably not live in the implementation file of a subclass for the sake of not causing confusion

Comment: first let me explain why i'm asking for code, personally when people just explain with words i don't fully understand the problem, to many people code examples are more intuitive than other methods, i'm one of those people

Comment: @Paul.s Depends on what he's trying to achieve and that's hard to tell from this question, but yes, good point.

Comment: @liva I don't see where I placed anything in the Base header file

Comment: @Paul what i am trying to achieve is a simple protected inheritance scenario where i have some helper properties & methods that should not be published to the "world" and should be override/ used in derived classes, for example a card game with a public flip method that calls an internal match method, the match algoritm is different in each derived cardGame class